# Deleting a BufferedImage drawn on another BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have a `BufferedImage` called `originalImage` that is drawn on a `JPanel`. I have an array of `BufferedImage` called `layer` and I draw all of those `layer` on the `originalImage`

So how can I delete (for example) `layer[0]` entirely from the `originalImage` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't! Just delete one layer entry and paint everything new. It's at low cost, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the position where you draw your `BufferedImage` (e.g. `layer[0]`). Then you can just overpaint this:

```
public void overpaintImage (BuffereImage originalImage, Point imagePos, Dimension imageSize)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(imagePos.x, imagePos.y, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    Graphics2D g = originalImage.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE); // or whatever your background color is
    g.fill(r);
}
```

Comment: The Problem is that if I fill the layer with clear Rectangle that white Rectangle may ruin other layer :(

Comment: @eyadkht Then you'll need to clear your whole `BufferedImage` and draw the rest of your layer-array again on it